# Each Result in Table <TD>

Tags: windows, powershell, html

I have a PowerShell Script, which contain `$frcnt` Variable, it will gives a tow condition array:
 1. `Values`: Name of process (without duplicates).
 2. `Keys`: How many duplicates process. 
i want to show each above array in HTML table such as:

```
Keys         Values
chrome       10
explorer     5
firefox      7
```

**here's my wrong syntax:**

```
    $GetCon = Get-NetTCPConnection


$GName = foreach ($process in $GetCon) {

    $processName = (Get-Process -Id $process.OwningProcess).ProcessName
    $process | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ProcessName -NotePropertyValue $processName -PassThru
}

$gnmcnt = $GetCon | select -ExpandProperty ProcessName
$frcnt=@{}
$gnmcnt | % {if (!($frcnt.ContainsKey($_))) {$frcnt.Add($_,1)} else {$frcnt.Item($_)=$frcnt.Item($_) +1}}




$TableBody,$StrBody=""


$frcnt | ForEach-Object {

$TableBody+="<tr><td>$($_.Keys)</td> <td>$($_.Values)</td></tr>"

}


$Body =@"
<table>
<th>Process</th><th>Count</th>
$TableBody
</table>
"@

$Head = "<Style> body {Background-color: lightblue; } table {background-color: white; margin: 5px; float: left; top: 0px; display: inline-block; padding:5px; border: 1px solid black} tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: lightgray} </style>"


$HTML = ConvertTo-Html -Body $Body -Head $Head


$HTML | Out-File -filepath "C:\temp\test.html" -Force

Invoke-Item "C:\temp\test.html"
```

Her's a result:
[image]

**Again**: I want to each result show's in  with count values. thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to look where in the code it goes wrong and how to fix it, but I can tell you, you are not working with an array, there's only one result.

Comment: @LPChip you'r right, in fact as you see in the image result, it show's all process in one table row <tr>. why? i don't know why! please could you show me an simple example to show all results in each tr? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the hashtable $frcnt to an array you can use the .GetEnumerator method.
.Keys changes to .Name then. and
.Values to singular .Value

Change the lines

```
$frcnt | ForEach-Object {
  $TableBody+="<tr><td>$($_.Keys)</td> <td>$($_.Values)</td></tr>"
}
```

to

```
$frcntArr = $frcnt.GetEnumerator() |%{$_}
ForEach ($Row in $frcntArr) {
  $TableBody+="<tr><td>$($Row.Name)</td> <td>$($Row.Value)</td></tr>`r`n"
}
```

---

**Edit**

or still better this, with only one Foreach

```
$frcnt.GetEnumerator() | ForEach {
  $TableBody+="<tr><td>$($_.Name)</td> <td>$($_.Value)</td></tr>`r`n"
}
```

Comment: can i ask something else, please?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign Yes of course. But question of public interrest are better put into a new question.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, I want to add CopyRight Member to Get-Process, Here is my wrong syntax, please fix it: 
[Link of My Script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3L7ZNJaTcIhN3d5RjMwSjdrcUE/view)

Comment: @SchoolforDesign Sorry but comments aren't adequate for new questions. I dont' know what you expect vs what you get, which errors occur. So please open a new questions and others can participate.

Comment: @ LoiPngs it say (question limit) for me, but you know I will ask something else, which is get or create a new member for Get-Process, which is CopyRight for each process, I have an script to do that, but it doesn't show any thing, here is my script in google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3L7ZNJaTcIhN3d5RjMwSjdrcUE

Comment: her's my new question, as you say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791316/add-copyright-as-a-new-member-to-get-process

Comment: @SchoolforDesign remembered a simpler version with only one Foreach. Hmm, a new user to circumvent new question restrictions...